# C - printing a grid with a pointer to an array of characters

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am working on an exercise that asks:

"Write a program that declares a 12x12 array of characters.  Place X's in every other element.  Use a pointer to the array to print the values to the screen in a grid format."

My code provides strange characters instead of X's when I compile.  My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char multi[12][12];
    char (*ptr)[12];
    ptr = multi;
    int ctr1, ctr2;

    for (ctr1 = 0; ctr1 < 12; ctr1++)
    {
        for (ctr2 = 0; ctr2 < 12; ctr2++)
        {
            if ((ctr2 % 2) == 0)
            {
                multi[ctr1][ctr2] = 'X';
            }
            else
            {
                multi[ctr1][ctr2] = ' ';
            }

        }
    }

    for (ctr1 = 0; ctr1 < 12; ctr1++)
    {
        for (ctr2 = 0; ctr2 < 12; ctr2++)
        {
            printf("%c\t", *ptr++);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why bother with the `ptr` just print from the array directly the same way you are putting the data in?

Comment: Because I'm trying to learn how to use pointers correctly and I'm not sure why this didn't work.

Comment: I have added detail to my answer about why it has failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the comments of the code. You should use a simple pointer to the array, as the assignment says.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char multi[12][12];

    // The assignment says, use a pointer to the array.
    // Our array holds characters, thus we need a pointer to char.
    char *p;

    // Assign where multi points to, as value of p.
    // Now p points at the 1st element of multi, i.e. multi[0][0]
    p = *multi;
    int ctr1, ctr2;

    for (ctr1 = 0; ctr1 < 12; ctr1++)
    {
        for (ctr2 = 0; ctr2 < 12; ctr2++)
        {
            if ((ctr2 % 2) == 0)
            {
                multi[ctr1][ctr2] = 'X';
            }
            else
            {
                multi[ctr1][ctr2] = ' ';
            }

        }
    }

    for (ctr1 = 0; ctr1 < 12; ctr1++)
    {
        for (ctr2 = 0; ctr2 < 12; ctr2++)
        {
          // Remember that * operator has higher priority than ++
          printf("%c\t", *p++);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
X       X       X       X       X       X       
X       X       X       X       X       X       
X       X       X       X       X       X       
X       X       X       X       X       X       
X       X       X       X       X       X       
X       X       X       X       X       X       
X       X       X       X       X       X       
X       X       X       X       X       X       
X       X       X       X       X       X       
X       X       X       X       X       X       
X       X       X       X       X       X       
X       X       X       X       X       X
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `ptr` is declared as a pointer to `char[12]`. Therefore the compiler adds 12 to `ptr` when you post-increment with `ptr++`. Given the way the loops are written, you only want `ptr` to advance by 1 when incremented.

So you could fix it by declaring `ptr` as a simple `char *`.  This works because the rows of a two-dimensional array are contiguous in memory, so incrementing past the end of a row just moves the pointer to the first element of the next row.

Or you can fix it by using your existing `char (*)[12]`. To do that, you need to understand that incrementing `ptr` will move your pointer to the next row of the array. To access the various columns of the current row, you just treat the `ptr` variable like it was a one-dimensional array.  Hence, the code looks like this

```
for ( row = 0; row < 12; row++ )
{
    for ( col = 0; col < 12; col++ )
    {
        printf( "%c\t", (*ptr)[col] );  // print out the columns for the current row
    }
    printf("\n");
    ptr++;         // move to the next row
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`ptr` points to *a whole row at a time* of the array. When you increment it , it moves onto the next row.

One solution would just be to index off of it , then technically you have used a pointer:

```
for (ctr1 = 0; ctr1 < 12; ctr1++)
{
    for (ctr2 = 0; ctr2 < 12; ctr2++)
    {
        printf("%c\t", ptr[ctr1][ctr2]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

However,probably the question's intent was to use a `char *` to "flatten" the array, and they used sloppy language in their question:

```
char *ptr = (char *)&multi;
// ...
     printf("%c\t", *ptr++);
```

Answer (score 0):

> My code provides strange characters instead of X's when I compile. My code is as follows:

I've modified your code as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char multi[12][12];
    char (*ptr)[12];
    ptr = multi;
    int ctr1, ctr2;

    for (ctr1 = 0; ctr1 < 12; ctr1++)
    {
        for (ctr2 = 0; ctr2 < 12; ctr2++)
        {
            if ((ctr2 % 2) == 0)
            {
                multi[ctr1][ctr2] = 'X';
            }
            else
            {
                multi[ctr1][ctr2] = ' ';
            }

        }
    }

    for (ctr1 = 0; ctr1 < 12; ctr1++)
    {
        for (ctr2 = 0; ctr2 < 12; ctr2++)
        {
            printf("%c\t", *(*(ptr+ctr1)+ctr2) );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

You will note the following:

```
printf("%c\t", *(*(ptr+ctr1)+ctr2) );
```

Rationale:

char (*ptr)[12];

Denotes ptr, that is an array of 12 pointers to char ([c declaration syntax](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html)).

The name of the array [decays into pointers](http://web.archive.org/web/20081208122434/http://www.transcendentaxis.com/dthompson/blog/archives/9), therefore:

ptr is an array of 12 "pointers to char". This represents the 12 rows of your double subscript array (or 12 arrays to char, each of their first items being able to decay to a pointer to chars). If you dereference ptr, you get a "pointer to char", as it decayed to a pointer to a "array to chars", each of who's itself decays to a "pointer to char array" (which if dereferenced gives a char).

1. "*(ptr+ctr1)" -> char*" -> rows of your array, each being a character pointer
2. "*(expr(1)+ctr2) -> char" -> items in each row, each being a character.

Comment: bloody confusing...;-)